# Application backup/restore - for saving resources

Tags: backup, internal-storage, restore, storage, backup-manager

I was thinking I could completely backup apps to the SD card, and then restore them when needed.  This for saving system resources.

Is there some efficient way to do this?

Comment: `adb backup` or [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) or go into Settings > Backup & Reset > Backup my data/Backup account (from ICS onwards) for GB(Settings > Privacy Settings > Backup my data) is your friend

Comment: @t0mm13b: that seems an answer, rather than a comment. Maybe even it's the correct answer.

Comment: @FranciscoAlvarado have created an answer from the comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous options available to you:

- [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup)
- For ICS upwards, Settings > Backup & Reset > Backup my data/Backup account
- For GB, Settings > Privacy Settings > Backup my data
- Last but not least, `adb backup`

In that order of "user-friendliness", from a android application that requires rooted access, in reference to Titanium Backup, to the least, using the command line `adb backup`.

Comment: Titanium seems OK - Will write more later.

Answer (score 1):

*If it is just the **"user"** and **"system"** applications*, I do this sort of thing all the time. In fact I wrote an app to help me out with this. I uninstall and re-install applications for testing a development all the time. I need to easily be able to make copies and move ".apk" files all the time.

Please take a look at the free app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=burrows.apps.appmanager.

Simple install the app, "backup" your application of choice and then share/send the application(.apk) to another phone.

Regards,

Comment: Are you affiliated with the app?

Comment: Yeah, I've never really seen anyone ask for backing up. I wrote this to safely backup applications without messing with user's data for privacy and security reasons. Just trying to be helpful. I mainly use for development.

Answer (score 1):

If your device is running Android 4.0 or higher, [*Carbon - App Sync and Backup*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=en) would be the perfect solution, and does not even require root -- but still is capable of backing up apps including their data:

[image: Carbon Backup]
<sup>Carbon App Sync and Backup</sup>

As above screenshots show, you can backup/restore single apps, or select a batch. What you cannot see on the screenshots: you can also save a selection as "group", so for the next backup/restore you don't need to select apps separately, but simply select the group instead.

With *Carbon Backup*, one should be able to backup apps and data to SD card, attached USB devices, Dropbox, GoogleDrive, etc.